# Is it possible in Minecraft to switch over from survival to creative in single player?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

This question is regarding the minecraft Beta 1.8 prerelease -- I have a beautiful house in single player survival which I'd like to record while flying.

I want to be able to change the game mode of my survival map to creative to be able to fly through it without installing a mod. I know it is possible if you run the map on a multiplayer server via the command `/gamemode <user> 0|1` but I want to achieve this in single player :)

I think this would be possible through editing your level.dat file as I think that's where the game mode for the map is stored.

Comment: I was wondering this for the other way round. For adventure maps and such!

Comment: Try this http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-tools/2667582-1-9-minecraft-game-mode-switcher

Comment: 1.13 syntax: `/gamemode <user> survival|creative(|adventure|spectator)`

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's `/gamemode (survival|creative|adventure|spectator) <target>`.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

As of Minecraft 1.3, singleplayer and multiplayer have been merged, so you can switch your gamemode with the [`/gamemode` command](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands):

- */gamemode survival*
- */gamemode creative*
- */gamemode adventure*

You can abbreviate the modes. For example, typing `/gamemode c` for Creative works as well.

You can only do this if you haven't disabled cheats during world generation, though.

If you turned cheats off and still want to do it for whatever reason: The game mode is stored in the `level.dat` file, which can be edited using an NBT editor, such as [NBTExplorer](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/840677-nbtexplorer-nbt-editor-for-windows-and-mac/). The game mode is stored in `Data/GameType`.

Comment: Thank you! I did not want to install any flying mod, since that seems overkill with creative mode having it's own. Since I don't need to change the game mode too often, using NBTedit will not be much of a hassle.

Comment: doesn't work, when i load the world it's back as before ò__ò

Comment: checked and confirmed it worked :]

Comment: Since your answer is top voted and accepted, could you update it to account for changes made in 1.3?

Comment: @MBraedley Well, it's not accepted anymore and since there's another answer now... meh, I'll do it anyway.

Comment: It is accepted, again :)

Comment: You can also use `/gamemode survival`, `/gamemode creative`, and `/gamemode adventure`, so you don't need to memorize which number refers to which game-mode.

Comment: @IQAndreas I think this wasn't possible back when I edited this, but yeah. Thanks for bringing it up.

Comment: You can no longer abbreivate the gamemode in 1.13

Answer (score 6):

I've found another tool (NBTEdit was unavailable when I tried to download it, so I poked around for alternatives).

The [Game Mode Switcher](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/638645-18-game-mode-switcher/) Is exactly what it says on the tin.

It's a simple, external application with the added option of culling your inventory when you switch modes.

[image]

Comment: Well I can't get NBTedit to work on Ubuntu, so here, have an upvote.

Comment: The is a new software like that, works for me http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-tools/2667582-1-9-minecraft-game-mode-switcher

Answer (score 4):

You can use /gamemode 0|1 now by starting your world with "Cheats Enabled".

Comment: 1.13 syntax: `/gamemode <survival|creative>`

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in-game and on-the-fly using the [TooManyItems](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/140684-100-toomanyitems-in-game-invedit-nov-29-saves-enchantments/) mod. Once installed, open your inventory press the <kbd>C</kbd> button in the toolbar to toggle between survival and creative mode:

[image: Image of TooManyItems]

*(Screenshot from thread)*

Comment: Is this a permanent switch or just for this session? At least with [NotEnoughItems](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/909223-110181-smp-chickenbones-mods/) (similar to TMI but with a lot of nice features added) this is setting only stays until logging off.

Answer (score 2):

Without Mods or software? Try Dumping your inventory in a chest, Create a new world that is creative mode, copy the level.dat in your new world to your old one (yes overwrite the old level.dat) then delete your new world as it was only temporary and you have no uses for it, then play your world, sorry if it bugs people that this is all 1 sentence!
Also note this will change your seed so input your old seed for the same generation or use a new one for some excitement!

Comment: nice idea, you should mention that the seed can be obtained by pressing F3