# My village appears to be a ghost town. How do I get my people back?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So I have been building up a village, hoping that the 3-4 block high wall would protect it from nasty predators, but apparently I was wrong.  I find it kind of weird that the smaller, wall-less village managed to maintain a population for so long, but my expanded and walled village is now apparently a ghost town.  Does anyone know why this may be?  (If so I'm opening [another thread for this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/64406/24647), as I think this is an entirely different line of questioning involving how hostile mobs spawn).

I'm wondering if there is some way I can repopulate the village, hopefully without having to transplant villagers (as villages appear to be extremely rare).  Is there anyway of doing this?  Building more houses doesn't appear to work.

Comment: Is the village sufficiently lit.

Comment: A related problem I had was that it was possible to jump out of the village, off the walls but never back in; causing the wall itself to depopulate the village

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm afraid there is no way to cause more villagers to spawn without going into creative mode and/or cheating in spawn eggs.

If you do attempt to move them, note that you only need 2, as [they will breed](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Villager#Mating_and_Population).

To prevent this from happening again, you can cause iron golems to spawn to protect your villagers by having at least 21 houses and 10 villagers.

To get ten villagers, you need to build 29 houses, but then you can cut them back down 21 if you want.

[Iron golems](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Iron_golems#Spawning) spawn every 10 villagers and 21 houses, so you could spawn several.

Comment: Yeah, I was afraid this was the case.  I think next time I need to do some combination of lighting up the interior of the city, building those houses quickly, and maybe building an iron golem just in case.  It's weird that only when I improved on the city was the population wiped out.  Does the main player attract mobs or something?

Comment: What do you mean by "going into creative mode"?  Is there some way of switching from survival mode to creative mode in the same world?  Or are you just suggesting that I start a new world?

Comment: @BrotherJack I can't find the post I read it in at the moment, but yes, the player *does* attract mobs.  Mobs spawn in a doughnut shape around the player.  [Re: Creative mode](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/30313/5029)

Comment: Well that explains why the town survived as long as it did.  I wasn't there.  OH GOD FORGIVE ME, I DID NOT MEAN TO KILL YOU ALL BY PARADING MY IRRESISTIBLE STEVE FLESH BEFORE THE ZOMBIE HORDES!!!

Comment: This did not cover why the village suddenly died. Zombie infections spread, so if a single zombie gets in (or spawns in a dark corner) he can kill a villager which turns to 2 which turns to 4 and very quickly your whole town can turn in to a town of zombies.

Comment: You didn't explain about curing zombie villagers. They turn back to normal ones.

Comment: @Jim There is a very good reason for that...at the time of this answer (April 2012) that mechanic did not exist.  In fact, zombie villagers themselves were not even added to the game until [October, 2012](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/1.4.2)

Comment: @JohntheGreen Okay.

Comment: So what if I make more buildings?  Would that cause another villager to spawn?  Then If I got two to spawn, they would mulitiply?

Answer (score 4):

Occasionally zombies will spawn as villager zombies [(5% of the time)](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Zombie) , these can be cured and returned to regular villagers. This is achieved by using a splash potion of weakness on them before feeding them a golden apple. Once given the apple they will begin to shake however it will take considerable time (minutes) before they are cured, they remain vulnerable to sunlight during this time.

Once you have cured 2 these can breed to repopulate your village

This is a considerable undertaking and requires several nights out "in the dark", it is best to avoid having to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when i used a seed and after the first couple of nights they were gone. there is no way to get them back unless in creative mode or an inventory hack. I feel a bit lonely now but there is a huge iron reserve and coal reserve near by. I think spiders might be yor problem. if you add an overhang it should stop spiders getting in.

Answer (score -1):

Do you have any dogs? If there is a dog in a village that is outside, they will disappear. I am not sure if this is intentional or not.

Comment: Do you have any proof of this?  It seems like a rather bold claim.