# Where can zombies spawn?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How Do Hostile Mobs Spawn in Minecraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/64406/how-do-hostile-mobs-spawn-in-minecraft)

I dug a 3x5x3 ditch, captured two zombies then put a brick roof over it. I open a little hole in it so I can capture new zombies. Now I have three zombies but I heard more than three zombie sounds at once. Could zombies spawn in that zombie jail? I have no torches in there.

Answer (score 1):

Zombies can spawn anywhere as long as there is a solid (and opaque) block beneath their feet, an air block at their feet and either air or a transparent block where their head is, it must also be beneath light level 7 at their feet and be more than 24 blocks from the player.

Please note that other mobs can also spawn under the same conditions, and that they will have a chance to despawn if you are more than 32 blocks away and will instantly despawn if you are more than 128 blocks away.

Comment: I don't understand, this answer implies a mob can spawn with his head in a block of glass...

Comment: @Lohoris actually that rule applies to the central area of a pack of mobs, the actual first mob wont appear with his head in the glass, but rather somewhere near the centrally located spawn block. check out the wiki for minecraft for more information.