# Is there a way to switch between adventure mode and creative mode in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible in Minecraft to switch over from survival to creative in single player?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/30311/is-it-possible-in-minecraft-to-switch-over-from-survival-to-creative-in-single-p)

There are times when I'm in a network of caves and I get so lost that I can't get back to the entrance and I'm out of materials to build pickaxes to mine upwards and because of the load of materials I just mined dying isn't an option (because if I do make it back I'll just be lost again)

At times like this I want to switch to creative mode and fly straight up and then back to my base. I know it's kind of cheating but I can sometimes spends hours being lost, markings don't help because of just how large of a labyrinth these mines are and I already carry a hell lot of tools I don't have the space to carry anything else to make markings with without running into problems of being able to cart the stuff back home.

Comment: Although I will add that it is now "officially" possible to switch between modes, but the map is required to be created with "Allow Cheats" selected.

Comment: Here's some advice on markings: Whenever you reach an intersection, place a block in the middle of the intersection, and put a torch on the side of the block pointing towards the way out.

Comment: Go to gamemode spectator instead of creative. This way you can fly through blocks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have cheats enabled in your game, you can use the command `/gamemode <playername> 1` to switch to creative mode. To switch back to survival mode, use `/gamemode <playername> 0`. And just to be thorough, to switch to adventure mode, use `/gamemode <playername> 2`.

Comment: will it affect any of my stats if i used that?

Comment: I believe it will restore your health and hunger. Can't remember for certain. It will leave your experience as it is.

Comment: Also, you can use /gamemode survival /gamemode creative and /gamemode adventure

Comment: @Timtech Ah, those must be new!

Comment: Yes, they are. You can also use the first letters s c and a.

Comment: @Timtech Very cool.

Comment: You can also use 0, 1, and 2 instead of s c and a. In the 1.8 snapshots, there is 3, which is the spectator mode.