# How do you turn off adventure mode in Minecraft 1.6.2

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

How do you turn off adventure mode in Minecraft 1.16.2

Answer (score 3):

### Multiplayer

You cannot turn it off without administrative access to the server. As OP, use `/gamemode survival` or `/gamemode creative`. You can also add playername in the end. `/gamemode survival Notch`

### [Singleplayer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/30311/is-it-possible-in-minecraft-to-switch-over-from-survival-to-creative-in-single-p)

If cheats are enabled, you can use `/gamemode` as described above. If cheats are disabled, launch the world in LAN mode and enable cheats. Then you can use `/gamemode`.