# How to make an Enderman stay?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm trying to draw a picture of an enderman but it keeps on teleporting...I want the enderman to stay so I can also stand beside in and press F5 then click fn then prt sc....Help?

Comment: If you want to draw an Enderman, just search it up on google.

Comment: I need the picture with me in it..But thanks anyway.

Comment: side note, F2 saves a screenshot to your minecraft folder which will save you a bit of time

Comment: Why don't you just take a picture of yourself, then find a picture of the enderman for reference, and then draw your picture? It seems rather elaborate to have to set up a shot with both of you in it.  Also, why not just be in 3rd person mode to start, walk up to the side of the enderman, turn away from them so you don't look at them (keep your crosshairs from crossing with the Enderman), then hit prt scr?  At night, they don't teleport nearly as much and you shouldn't have as much trouble with doing this.

Answer (score 7):

If you wear a pumpkin as helmet, the enderman won't be bothered either.

Comment: The problem with this, is you won't be able to get a good screen shot with a pumpkin in front of you.

Comment: Unless you press [F1] to hide the GUI including the pumpkinmask ;)

Comment: @Lars Ah yes of course.

Answer (score 5):

Endermen tend to teleport in random occasions, when you look directly at them, and when you attack them. This will be a difficult task, but try not to look too closely at one when you approach it to improve your chances of taking a picture with one.

As an alternative, you could press F5 twice to take a selfie next to an Enderman far off in the distance.

Answer (score 5):

If you are under the effects of an invisibility potion, the Endermen won't be able to see you; but as soon as you attack one, they will see you and attack you back.

Answer (score 2):

Endermen do not being bothered if you do not look directly at him, but his legs. It not prevents him to teleport, but if you are quick enough, you can take a selfie before he start teleport.

Answer (score 2):

If all you want is a screenshot with him, Endermen won't become aggressive when you look at them in creative mode.

You could start a temporary world in creative mode (or [switch gamemodes with commands](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/30313/17179)), take your screenshot, and then switch back to survival.

Answer (score 1):

This may already be answered, but you could also press <kbd>F2</kbd> (It may be <kbd>FN</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> depending on your computer) once to take a screenshot of it.

The screenshot will appear in the `/appdata/Roaming/.minecraft/screenshots/` directory (If on windows) or `/users/user/library/application support/minecraft/screenshots/` directory if on a mac.

Answer (score 0):

how about summoning him riding another entity that way he is controlled by the entity and also you can add slowness and summon them -1 under the ground so that the other entity gets cut off

Comment: It would be helpful if you included the commands to do so in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

To make Enderman stay in one place, let go into cobwebs since they can't teleport while stuck in cobwebs. Here you will be able to build your Enderman. If you want to examine closely, wear a pumpkin on your head so Endermen won't be hostile when looking at you. You might have to examine it in third person since the pumpkin blocks some image.

If you still can't do this, press F5 to take a screenshot of the Enderman.

Comment: `/summon Enderman ~ ~ ~ {NoAI:true}`

Comment: @aytimothycWhat is this about.

Answer (score -3):

Put an enderman in a obsidian room and he will not teleport

Comment: Can you elaborate? Why not? How?

Comment: This doesn't work. Endermen don't care about your puny obsidian, he can teleport to any valid place.