# Remove Lingering Potion

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Is there a way to remove lingering potions in Minecraft?  My oldest son made a Minecreaft world with lots of creative buildings and such, and my youngest son later placed tons of lingering potions, and now the Xbox freezes when trying to render all the lingering potions.  Is there a way to remove these lingering potions to make the Minecraft world usable again?

Comment: In Java edition it's `/kill @e[type=area_effect_cloud]`, I don't know if it works on console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this command works on xbox one & on pocket education: `/kill @e[type=area_effect_cloud]`
Inside an command block also you can use:
`/kill @e[type=area_effect_cloud,x=?,y=?,z=?,dx=?,dy=?,dz=?]`

Answer (score 0):

If you can use commands, or if you have a cow, you can use the [Milk Bucket](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Milk_Bucket) item to instantly remove all effects (emphasis mine):

> Holding use with a milk bucket will start the drinking sound and animation. When consumed it will **immediately remove any status effects from the player**.

The other solution might be to [change the game mode to creative](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/30311/is-it-possible-in-minecraft-to-switch-over-from-survival-to-creative-in-single-p). This could potentially help lighten the load on the processor, since it removes most of the interactive properties of the player.

The only other possible solution is create a copy of your Minecraft world in the world selection menu (I don't remember if this however creates a new copy of the same seed, or if it creates a duplicate of your world in the same state), or create a "backup" copy, delete the user properties, then reload it back onto your xbox.

> You can save a Minecraft world to external storage but you need a Windows 10 PC and a Minecraft Realm.
>
> 1. Copy local Minecraft world into the Realm.
> 2. Open Minecraft on Windows 10 PC
> 3. Make a local copy of that Realm.
> 4. Now you can create a file from that World and store it where ever you want.
>
> To load a saved file into the Minecraft xbox version it's just the same but backwards.

Comment: This does not answer the question. The question asked if there was a way to remove the particle clouds from a lingering potion, not if there was a way to remove the effect from the player itself.

Answer (score 0):

Turn on...
Weather Cycle and Day/Night Cycle.  This will trigger it to turn off. Lingering potions are by default time based. However Weather and Day must be set to cycle in order for it to end.

Comment: I am using this method on PS4 and XBOX One.