# I have an area where the gamemode will be Adventure mode, But I can't figure out what command to use or where to make the gamemode survival if outside

Tags: minecraft-commands, cheats

I don't know what commands to use in command blocks nor know where to place them. I have a command block with a command to change into adventure mode in a radius of 5, and it works. But i dont know how to let it change back to survival once you leave that area. It's for a circular spawn.

ALL HELP IS APPRECHIATED!!:D

Comment: Related: [Is it possible in Minecraft to switch over from survival to creative in single player?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/30311). I was sure we had a duplicate of switching them back and forth, but you might want to look at existing questions asking after the use of command blocks in specific areas, like [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=minecraft+command+block+area).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to set an "Adventure Mode Boundary" in Minecraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/229652/is-there-a-way-to-set-an-adventure-mode-boundary-in-minecraft)

Comment: First of all.. which version of Minecraft are you playing?